# Angular (4): ngFor in batches?

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects called `applicationArray` with 12 'application' elements. I need to show these `application` by using bootstrap `div.row` and `div.col-sm-4` in batches of 3 `application` per row.

Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 p-top-buffer">
      <application></application>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 p-top-buffer">
      <application></application>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 p-top-buffer">
      <application></application>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it somehow possible to use `ngFor` and tell it to divide the array into batches and display it dynamically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a function that splits it into batches in the component, then render each batch in the template:

Template:

```
 <div *ngFor="let batch of batches" class="row">
         <div *ngFor="let application of batch" class="col-sm-4 p-top-buffer">
           {{application.number}}
         </div>
     </div>
```

Component:

```
 batches = [];

   ngOnInit(){
     this.splitIntoBatchesOfThree(this.applicationArray);
   }

   constructor() {}

   splitIntoBatchesOfThree(applicationArray)
   {
    while(applicationArray.length) {
        this.batches.push(applicationArray.splice(0,3));
    }
  }
```

Here's a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/prkYEaDc8rpJI1hR8tqE?p=preview

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I decided to go with angular material 2 `grid-list` which basically does all of this for you. You just specify the columns and it draws rows in accordance to the size of this parameter and array size.

Comment: sounds really nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product  of applicationArray;let i = index"">
 <div  *ngIf="i % 3 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">  <application></application></div>
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is angular 4. You're providing syntax for angular 1.x :)

Comment: @DenissM. updating it :)

Comment: You can't have multiple template bindings on one element.

Comment: and now $index is not defined :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154708/discussion-between-deniss-m-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 0):

pack them in batches of 3 in our backend:

if you have 12 `applications[]` pack them in 4 `applicationBatches` like

```
applicationBatches = [
[application1, application2, application3],
[application4, application5, application6]
...
]
```

if you introduce some `applicationBatchSize` setting you could have a function that receives a batch size and packs accordingly. That way you have a clean template just binding outer/inner collections.